# How does Anki structure when to show new words? Ex. it seems to often show words that are related in certain ways

Tags: anki

I have been using Anki for learning a language. The deck i'm using seems to often present new words that are "thematically" related together ex. monitor, keyboard, desktop,printer. However, not all words are together like that. For example, the words computer and mouse were presented earlier and at a different times. This doesn't seem to be the order they were added to the deck. I also find that it will usually present words in the same session that have similar spellings but mean different things.

I've found this helpful so far, but how does Anki actually know to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Anki itself does not order the cards in the deck. The person who has made the deck has set the cards in a particular order there.

(You can also choose to see the cards in a random order, but that is probably not useful for you.)